# MySQL 5.1.61 - Update table based on two seperate tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
Table_1:
id   name
1    NULL
2    OLED   
3    legion 
4    project100 
5    group3 
6    0  
7    25 

Table_2:
projectID   externalID  projectTypeID   projectDescription 
0           0               5               UNALLOCATED
25          220339          1               OLED

Table_3:
typeID   typeDesc   
1        Playbook Aligned
2        Transactional Project
3        External Programs
4        UPI
5        Unallocated
```

I am trying to update Table_1. I only want to update rows with a 'name' that is a digit. I know that I can select those by doing:

```
SELECT `name`
FROM `Table_1`
WHERE `name` REGEXP '^[0-9]*$'
```

This gives me:

```
name    
0
25
```

What I want to do now is to update these Table_1 entries based on Table_2 and Table_3. I need to find the row in Table_2 where Table_2.projectID = Table_1.name. Then, I need to find the row in Table_3 where Table_3.typeID = Table_2.projectTypeID. Finally, I need to update Table_1.name with Table_3.typeDesc. It's a confusing situation - unfortunately I can't do much to change the way that these tables are set up. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE
Table_1
JOIN Table_2 on(Table_2.projectID = Table_1.name)
JOIN Table_3 on(Table_3.typeID = Table_2.projectTypeID)
SET Table_1.name = Table_3.typeDesc
WHERE Table_1.name REGEXP '^[0-9]*$';
```

Comment: also, if the tables will grow, remeber to add an index to the involved rows, otherwise a query with to joins could take forever

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much. One small issue though - for some reason the Table_1 row with ID = 1 turns into 'Unallocated'. I think the regex is having issues - any way to fix it?

Comment: UPDATE - fixed by changing to '^[0-9]+$'.